# Job boards for university positions in Math Education?

Tags: undergraduate-education, employment

What are the most important websites where university jobs in Math Education are advertised? The kind of boards I am looking for should preferably be able to reach an international audience.

Comment: I'm asking because my university (in Norway) wants to advertise such a position, I'm not a job seeker myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main place of which I am aware is the math education listserv run by [**Dr. Jerry Becker**](http://ehs.siu.edu/ci/faculty-staff/faculty-all/becker.php).

I suggest that you contact him to ask about listing a position; he will send it out with a subject line that begins "Position Announcement"; early September is not the most common time to list a position, but here is a screenshot of his listings from 27 Oct 2015 - 18 Dec 2015 to give you a sample glimpse:

[image]

(Click through to see an enlarged image.)

I suggested as a side-note back in [**MESE 8193**](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/8203) that math educators should also *subscribe* to Dr. Becker's listserv; I reiterate that suggestion here!

Comment: Benjamin: Can you share exactly how to join Dr. Becker's listserv?

Comment: @DanielR.Collins I emailed Dr. Becker  -- jbecker{at]siu{dot}edu -- to say, *Dear Dr. Becker: I was wondering if you could add me to your listserv concerning position announcements for mathematics educators. Please let me know if you have any questions, or if there is a better way to subscribe to the listserv.* He wrote back to say, *Thank you for your note. I have added [my email address] to the USA, BIG and MTE lists.*

Answer (score 4):

In the U.S., [MathJobs.org](https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs) dominates.

> Mathjobs.org is an automated job application system, sponsored by the *American Mathematical Society*. We serve all job applicants with advanced degrees in Mathematics, and employers (academic or industrial) searching for mathematicians. The system is free for applicants.

Despite its U.S. focus, they are international to some extent:

---

[image]

          

<sup>(Image from [www.mathjobs.org](https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs).)</sup>

---

Answer (score 1):

[HigherEdJobs.com](https://www.higheredjobs.com/) is fairly prominent, I think. It has a U.S. focus but does permit a non-U.S. location, for example: [this search](https://www.higheredjobs.com/search/advanced_action.cfm?JobCat=104&PosType=1&PosType=2&InstType=1&InstType=2&InstType=3&Keyword=&Remote=1&Remote=2&Region=10&SubRegions=75&Submit=Search%20Jobs).

Answer (score 1):

I used the Chronicle of Higher Education when I looked for jobs. Is it still useful? (They now have a special site for jobs, [chroniclevitae.com](https://chroniclevitae.com/).)

Answer (score 1):

Although MathJobs was mentioned, there is a larger list (or perhaps it *was* a larger list) at the [Employment Information in the Mathematical Sciences](http://eims.ams.org/jobs/) website, also by the AMS.  It is not an application site, though (as opposed to MJ), and I don't know how many math ed jobs there would be - today it was everything from OR to stats to 'math curriculum designer' (whatever that is) to various postdocs.